# Javafx ListView refreshing

Tags: listview, javafx-2

Is there any way to force a ListView refresh in Javafx 2.1  without reloading the list and changing the selected value?

The observable list is made of Strings so changing their value is not feasible.

Comment: where were a lot of similar questions about tableview. E.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912690/updating-rows-in-tableview

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I don't want to change any visible property.  There should be a way to programmatically make a list update,  with a single call.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
...
ObservableList<String> olist = ... 
ListView<String> listv = ...
...
listv.setItems(null); 
listv.setItems(olist);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have tried it and it works, but it causes a blink in some of the fields which is annoying when you are refreshing once per second.  I found another more ellaborate way of doing it that works fine for my needs.  If anyone needs it, just ask so I will post it.

Comment: @betaman, please post your solution - i am stuck with the same problem :( thanks!

Comment: @bennyl  There are plenty of solutions, better than mine, in the Jira link I posted above.   Choose one and take the chance to vote so they fix it in a future Javafx version.    https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22599

Comment: @MustafaErdemKöşk  I just posted an answer with my code.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the String values with Property like `SimpleStringProperty` and changing this property's value should be feasible.

Comment: Thank you Uluk.  That is a possible solution.  But I so much wish there was some kind of "refresh" command in ListView and TableView

Comment: I just created it:  http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22599. 
Anyone that would like this feature implemented is invited to visit that address and vote for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
private static final ObservableList<String> lists = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...


synchronized(lists) {
        List<String> lsts = new ArrayList<>();
        lsts.addAll(lists);
        lists.clear();
        lists.addAll(lsts);            
    }
```

Comment: What is `synchronized`?